# How to remove any elements that DO NOT have a hyphen in it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tag list that has mostly tags that start with a hyphen. I want to remove or hide all tags that DO NOT have this character. Because of limited access to code, it has to be done with jQuery/javascript. My attempt doesn't work, how to fix?

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="widget Label" data-version="2" id="Label1">
  <h3 class="title">
    Tags
  </h3>
  <div class="widget-content cloud-label-widget-content">
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/art">
        art
        <span class="label-count">
          10
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-gallery">
        -gallery
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-photography">
        -photography
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-portfolio">
        -portfolio
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/opinion">
        opinion
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#label1').each(function() {
    $('#label1 span').find(':not(:contains("-"))').remove();
});
```

Comment: Well first problem is that it's `$('#Label1')` not `$('#label1')`

Comment: instead of looking for `-` in the text make it easy on yourself and add a class like next to `label-size` called `hidden`, then use js to hide or toggle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(`.label-size:not(:contains("-"))`).remove();
});
```

Vanilla JavaScript

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  for(let node of document.getElementsByClassName("label-size")) {
    if(!/-/.test(node.textContent)) {
      node.remove();    
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.label-size').each((element) => { 
element.textContent.indexOf('-') >= 0 ? element.remove() : null;
});
```

Something like that should work. You need to check each label-size element, so looping over a unique identifier like an id won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Follows a full working example, using vanilla javascript:

```js
// Gets the dom element which id="Label1"
const labelDiv = document.getElementById("Label1");

// Gets all elements which has the css class name 'label-name'
const labelNameElements = labelDiv.getElementsByClassName("label-name");

// For each element 'label-name' dom element
for(let i=0; i < labelNameElements.length; i++) {
     
     // Verifies if the element contains a '-'
     if(labelNameElements[i].text.indexOf('-') > -1) {
        
        //removes the parent element (in this case the <span class="label-size label-size-...">
        labelNameElements[i].parentElement.remove();
        
        //removes 1 to the index since a element was removed from the labelNameElements array.
        i--;
     }     
}
```

```html
<div class="widget Label" data-version="2" id="Label1">
  <h3 class="title">
    Tags
  </h3>
  <div class="widget-content cloud-label-widget-content">
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/art">
        art
        <span class="label-count">
          10
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-gallery">
        -gallery
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-photography">
        -photography
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-portfolio">
        -portfolio
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/opinion">
        opinion
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer works with jQuery:

```js
$('.label-size').each(function() {

    $(this).find(':not(:contains("-"))').remove();
    
});
```

```css
.label-name {
  display:block; /* Optional, adds space between links*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="widget Label" data-version="2" id="Label1">
  <h3 class="title">
    Tags
  </h3>
  <div class="widget-content cloud-label-widget-content">
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/art">
        art
        <span class="label-count">
          10
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-gallery">
        -gallery
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-photography">
        -photography
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-portfolio">
        -portfolio
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/opinion">
        opinion
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem was that the code wasn't using its own element inside the `.each` function, and it wasn't using the correct element.

Also, if you want a one liner, there's a much easier way to do this:

`$(`.label-size:not(:contains("-"))`).remove();`

Comment: I don't want to remove those that have a hyphen, I want to remove the ones that don't.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding! fixed it.

Comment: @Xarcell actually your title says: How to remove any elements that have a hyphen in it

Answer (score 0):

This is a jQuery solution, if you want a vanilla JS try @Ricardo Rocha solution:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const tags = $(".label-name");
  tags.each(function(index, element) {
    element.text.trim().startsWith("-") ? '' : element.remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.label-name {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="widget Label" data-version="2" id="Label1">
  <h3 class="title">
    Tags
  </h3>
  <div class="widget-content cloud-label-widget-content">
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/art">
        art
        <span class="label-count">
          10
        </span>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-gallery">
        -gallery
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-photography">
        -photography
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/-portfolio">
        -portfolio
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
    </a>
    </span>
    <span class="label-size label-size-5">
      <a class="label-name" href="https://about.xarcell.studio/search/label/opinion">
        opinion
        <span class="label-count">
          9
        </span>
    </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```